# List version limits client-side

Tags: web-services, client-object-model, version-history

Versioning can be defined the same way in UI in SP2013 and O365:

[image: versioning settings]

How can we programmatically set these limits in SP2013 without server-side code?

Server-side we would have [SPList.MajorVersionLimit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splist.majorversionlimit.aspx) and [SPList.MajorWithMinorVersionsLimit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splist.majorwithminorversionslimit%28v=office.15%29.aspx) but the [members of client-side List](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.client.list_members%28v=office.15%29.aspx) do not contain these properties.

Comment: powershell will solve your problem, will it work?

Comment: We have to use Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll (and other client-side libraries) or web services; we cannot use powershell with server-side API (Microsoft.SharePoint.dll / SPList).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll` with version 15.0.4665.1000 and above provide the `MajorVersionLimit`-property. If you can upgrade to the latest CU you should be doing fine.

Comment: Dec 2014 CU - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vesku/archive/2014/12/15/latest-api-updates-in-client-side-object-model-dec-2014-cu-for-sp2013.aspx

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this using CSOM. This is a limitation of CSOM. However, if you can use templates to create document libraries or lists then you can do it in the template itself. Use CSOM to create document libraries or lists using the pre-defined templates where version settings are pre-configured.

Answer (score 1):

Stumbled the same issue. No solution yet.

I posted it as a feedback at OfficeDev UserVoice, hope it will be fixed soon or later - [MajorVersionLimit & MajorWithMinorVersionsLimit props for List in CSOM/REST](http://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/suggestions/6016131-majorversionlimit-majorwithminorversionslimit-pr)

Comment: Upvoted it. It's still in the "Ivestigation Queue"